# PCL Trunk and ROS Hydro - Assembler Messages

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm playing with Kinfu in PCL, so I had to clone and compile the PCL trunk from bitbucket. However, one of my own packages does not compile anymore using catkin_make:

> /tmp/ccj7RxYq.s: Assembler messages:

> /tmp/ccj7RxYq.s:865: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312sd
> (%rbx,%rdi,8),%xmm5,%xmm4'

> [...]

The file that the errors seem to be related to does not contain anything related to assembler code. The includes are:
"Eigen/Dense", <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>, and <pcl/search/organized.h>.

When I restrict the compiler flags to *-fopenmp -Wno-deprecated*, it compiles fine. However, when adding *-DNDEBUG -O3*, the errors occur.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144136/pcl-trunk-and-ros-hydro---assembler-messages/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-03-25**:\

- What compiler (version) do you use?
- What CPU do you have?

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-26**:
Compiler: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5). CPU model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think Haswell support was added in gcc 4.7. I suppose you are using Ubuntu 12.04. I know 2 solutions:

1. You can update gcc:
   You can add a PPA ([https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test)) and update to 4.7 or 4.8. I'm using this PPA with Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.7, i7-4770 and PCL/KinFu.
2. You can use compiler flags to specify the architecture (e.g. "-march=corei7"). This should work, but it maybe not allows to use the full potential of the CPU.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-26**:
Changing the optimization level to O2 helped.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2014-03-26**:
I am not surprised by that. But this is like solution 2, you just don't use this Fused Multiply-Add instructions.